# Devise token authentication and session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, devise

I am using devise in my rails app.  There is an ipad app that connects to the this rails app and authentication is done using token. (devise token_authenticatable).

For sessions, I using the default cookie store. My session_stor.rb looks like this,

```
Ap::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store
```

Now say I need to store minor data for the ipad user in session, where is it stored? Say in my controller I am doing,

```
session['last_search'] = search_key_word
```

Where is this data stored? I am asking this because on cookie based session store, usually session data is stored in browser. I couldn't find any resource that explains what happens in case of a non browser client that uses token for authenticatication.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the history locally in the  iPad's app itself. You can create a table "search_history" that stores the recent 10 keywords. Or you may cache it if you want (also on the client side).

Comment: So my question was regarding where a session cookie is stored, in a ipad or android app. I was using the recent search as an example.But thanks for the reply.